# Is there a way to restart a for loop at its last index in R?

Tags: r, for-loop, data-processing

I am in the process of downloading and processing a substantial amount of air quality data from an API through the *jsonlite* library in R. Because of the amount of data, I thought it prudent to write a script that would automate the entire process. These data encompass all 50 States throughout the US, as well as four different air pollutants. The timeline for this is January 1st, 2015 through December 31st, 2019. The state, air pollutant code, begin date, and end date are the four parameters that are submitted at each query iteration to the API.

Since I know this will take quite a bit of time to download and process all the data, I am wondering if there is a way that I can run the script for a while, stop it when I need to do something else, and then restart the script at its last iteration, or rather, at its last index in the vectors containing the values passed into the API URL. I did look up other similar questions but could not find something that accurately fit my situation.

Because this script is querying a web API, I thought that the best approach in this case would be to automate the API calls and data processing through nested for loops. For the "for loop" portion, it would begin on the first state, first pollutant parameter, and then iterate through each beginning date and end date (the API only accepts timelines of up to one year). Then it would go to the next pollutant and iterate through each beginning date and ending date, so on and so forth. Is there a way I could keep track of the iterations and pass that back into the for loops once I restart the script? I am struggling to come up with the logic for this.

Also, I am still familiarizing myself with R after doing much of my data processing in Python and SQL, so please bear with me if my code is not very efficient or more complicated than what is necessary. I did not include the actual data processing portion of the code, only the vectors and the for loops for iterating through those vectors.

```
#set working directory
setwd('Path_to_directory_here')

#import jsonlite library
library(jsonlite)

#create state FIPS list 
fips_list <- c("01","02","04","05",
               "06","08","09","10",
               "12","13","15","16",
               "17","18","19","20",
               "21","22","23","24",
               "25","26","27","28",
               "29","30","31","32",
               "33","34","35","36",
               "37","38","39","40",
               "41","42","44","45",
               "46","47","48","49",
               "50","51","53","54",
               "55","56")

#create list of state names corresponding with state FIPS codes
#this was created to specify which state the data is from in the file name when writing to a .CSV file
fips_names <- c('AL','AK','AZ','AR',    
                'CA','CO','CT','DE',    
                'FL','GA','HI','ID',    
                'IL','IN','IA','KS',    
                'KY','LA','ME','MD',
                'MA','MI','MN','MS',    
                'MO','MT','NE','NV',    
                'NH','NJ','NM','NY',    
                'NC','ND','OH','OK',    
                'OR','PA','RI','SC',    
                'SD','TN','TX','UT',    
                'VT','VA','WA','WV',    
                'WI','WY')

#create a key/value pair for FIPS codes and state names
fips_states <- setNames(as.list(fips_names), fips_list)
fips_key <- names(fips_states)
fips_val <- fips_states[fips_list]

#same procedure as FIPS codes and state names 
param_list <- c('88101','88501', '42602','44201')
param_names <- c('PM25', 'PM25_LC', 'NO2', 'O3') #specifies which pollutant was pulled in the file name
params <- setNames(as.list(param_names), param_list)
param_key <- names(params)
param_val <- params[param_list]

#same as above
begin_yr <- c('20150101','20160101','20170101','20180101','20190101')
end_yr <- c('20151231','20161231','20171231','20181231','20191231')
yr_list <- setNames(as.list(end_yr), begin_yr)
key <- names(yr_list)
val <- yr_list[begin_yr]

#keep track of files processed 
file_tracker <- 0

for (x in 1:length(fips_states)) {
    for (y in 1:length(params)) {
        for (z in 1:length(yr_list)) {
           file_tracker = file_tracker + 1
           tracker_msg <- sprintf('Reading in State: %s, parameter: %s, timeframe: %s', fips_val[x], param_val[y], key[z])
           print(tracker_msg)
           #call to API 
           url <- sprintf("https://aqs.epa.gov/data/api/sampleData/byState?email=MY_EMAIL&key=MY_KEY&param=%s&bdate=%s&edate=%s&state=%s", 
           param_key[y],key[z],val[z],fips_key[x])
           data <- fromJSON(txt = url)
           #rest of the data formatting and processing here
         }
       }
     }
```

I can include more code if necessary. Thanks for any help provided.

Comment: At a minimum, add a `save()` command every 100th or 1,000th iteration.  The short wait to write the data to disk in the loop is worth every millisecond compared to a crash where you lose all data in memory (and thus all progress!).

Comment: Why not simply temporarily store the values of your loop counters x, y and z and then next time start insetad of starting the loop with `for (x in 1:...)` you'd start it with `for(x in temp_x:...)`. However, this doesn't answer how you coudl pause or stop the loop for a while. As @DanY suggested, you might not only want to save every n-th iteration, but maybe just set limits for the loop counter and next time manyually increase it? So first iteration could be x in 1:10000, next one is 10001:50000 or so.